# Symmetric monoidal category with trivial switch morphisms

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, terminology, symmetric-monoidal-categories

Is there a specific terminology for a symmetric monoidal category in which for any object $x$ the switch map $x\otimes x\to x\otimes x$ is the identity ? (Or alternatively the action of the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$ on $x^{\otimes n}$ is trivial.)

Is there a paper or book I can cite where basic properties of such categories are derived ?

Comment: Do you know any examples other than the one object category?  For example, I don't think it ever happens for additive categories with an additive tensor product.

Comment: The example I have in mind is something like the 2-category featured in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Brauer+group (but I only care about the underlying 1-category), where the objects are Azumaya algebras, and the morphisms are bimodules realizing Morita equivalences. I actually am interested in a hermitian version, where the algebras have an involution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coincidentally, terminology for such categories has been introduced very recently:

- John C. Baez and Jade Master. Open Petri Nets.  Nov 2018. [arXiv:1808.05415](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.05415)

More precisely, the authors refer to a strict symmetric monoidal category in which (not only the associator and unitors but also) the symmetry
$$\sigma_{a,b} : a \otimes b \overset{\sim}\to b \otimes a$$
is the identity morphism as a **commutative monoidal category**, this being the same as a commutative monoid object in $(\mathrm{Cat},\times,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. This being said, this seems quite a lot stronger than what I'm thinking about (the example that prompted my question does not satisfy such a strong property). Is it possible that any monoidal category satisfying the property in my question is monoidally equivalent to one as in your answer ?

Comment: They are indeed equivalent in this way.

Comment: @SimonHenry Really?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg : You know the topic better than I do, but I was under the impression that an appropriate modification of the proof of the strictification theorem was proving this: the condition that the switch map $x \otimes x \rightarrow x \otimes x$ is the identity shows that more general permutation of identical objects in a tensor product all acts as the identity. So one can consider the category MC whose objects are multi-set of objects of C, and morphisms are map between their tensor product (for any ordering) ? $\otimes$ is union and is strictly commutative.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Why doesn't the argument presented by Simon Henry work? I had the same intuition: forcing self-symmetries to be identities implies coherence (there is a unique way to permute a given tensor product), and hence should lead to a strictification theorem where permutations are identities.

Comment: EDIT: according to [an article of Kim](https://www.sciencepublishinggroup.com/article/10.11648/j.pamj.20160505.13) (cited by the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+monoidal+category)), it is indeed true that, under some assumptions on size, a symmetric monoidal category is symmetric monoidal equivalent to a commutative monoidal category if and only if all its self-braidings are identities.

Answer (score 4):

In my [thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1716) I have named objects $x$ whose switch map $x \otimes x \to x \otimes x$ is the identity *symtrivial* (since I could not find any term in the literature). It was then used by others as well, but right now I can only find [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.07666v2) example.  Now it is reasonable to call a tensor category *symtrivial* when every object is symtrivial. The property in Noam's answer is *much stronger*.

Comment: Thank you, nice to see that I was not the first one to have to come up with a name. In the meantime I've been using "strongly symmetric", but "symtrivial" sounds good, if it's the term that has been used up to now I'll try to conform to it.

Comment: I would not say that this is a term which has been used up to now.

Comment: @CaptainLama Did you end up coming up with a terminology for such categories? (and not just for objects satisfying this property)

Comment: @LéoS. In my article I call both "strongly symmetric". (So the category is strongly symmetric iff all objects are strongly symmetric.) It seems people rediscover this notion once in a while (the sign of a good notion ?), I used Laplaza "Coherence for categories with group structure: an alternative approach" and Ulbrich "Kohärenz in Kategorien mit Gruppenstruktur" as useful earlier references.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I also commented Noam's answer with further questions, I would be interested if you have any thoughts on this